# Enable button when an item is selected in a dialog box

Tags: java, android

I have dialog box with a selectable items on it with a positive button "Next". The problem is when a user click on the "Next" button without selecting in the item. It becomes null. Now, solution is to disable the "Next" button initially and when an item is selected, it will be enabled.

Here is my code in dialog box

```java
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Select Type");
                    builder.setCancelable(false);

                    int checkedItem = -1;
                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(a, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            mTypes = b[which]; //Id instead of item
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, a[which] + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            getSubjects();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
```

Comment: make one item selected by default, or i think there should be dialog.setEnabled(false); in onclick method of positive button

Answer (score 0):

Might be not proper answer but why don't you just make your first item always select is this case value never in going to be null all you have to do

```
int checkedItem = 0; // you can given any number 0,1,2,3
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(a, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mTypes = b[which]; //Id instead of item
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, a[which] + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```